# How to prevent this route error in remote model validation ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-validation, remote-validation

I'm trying to validate email using this remote validation attribute, but I keep getting this error. Does anyone know the exact reason for this?

```
public class StudentVm
{
       public string Id { get; set; }
       [Required]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [Remote( "Test", "Validation", HttpMethod = "POST", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email.")]
       public string Email { get; set; }
}

//The validation controller
[Route("Validation/[action]")]
public class ValidationController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public async Task<IActionResult> Test(string Email)
   {
       return Json(false);
   }
}
```

**Error**

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Comment: change `[Route("Validation/[action]")]` to `[Route("[controller]")]` and change this `[HttpPost]` to `[HttpPost, Route("test")]`. That will give you are route of `/Validation/test` and you would have to post this: `"hello@world.com"` If you want to post the model you have above, then you would have to change `string email` to `[FromBody] StudentVm student`

Comment: I tried it, but not work for me

Comment: Could you share your package reference?It seems that you have used wrong package.